# Running a Python script on the client side from the server side

Tags: python

I have designed a website using Flask (Python 2.7). I have sent a Python script (`c.py`) to the client using the `send_file()` function.

Now I want to run `c.py` on the client system from the server side maybe by using my website itself or my system. Is there a possible way to do that?

Note: Client and server are on the same network.

Is it possible to write a python script which can run another python script on another system?

Comment: maybe you should better design your program in such way: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call ?

Comment: There are couple ways to do it. One easy way is through SSH (if running on Linux/Mac platform)

Comment: @py_dude thanks will look into it.

Comment: My server operates on windows. So I need help on that. @Vinny 16

Answer (score 1):

[exec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec)("input the content of your py file"), which supports dynamic execution of Python code.

A demo here: Suppose that you could run Python script on client side

=== Server Side ===

```
from flask import Flask, send_file
import StringIO

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    sio = StringIO.StringIO()
    sio.write('print("hello world")')
    sio.seek(0)
    return send_file(sio, attachment_filename="c.py")

app.run(debug=True)
```

=== Client Side ===

```
import requests

code = requests.get('http://localhost:5000').text
exec(code)  # <-----
```

Comment: How and where to use this?

Comment: When your client system receive c.py, pass the content of c.py into `exec`

Comment: I added a demo. But I do not know how your client looks like, so suppose that you could run Python script on client side.